# Get moment when view is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement a custom camera on a view that has both the camera and a section for the user to add comment. So far so good, but what I want is to get the moment when this view is dismissed and goes back to the previous view (something like the imagePicker(didFinishPickingImage)) and also pass the taken picture and comment as parameters. I think I should implement a protocol but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: what you want to do at that moment ?

Comment: I have an UIImage on one viewController, whenever I dismiss this viewController I want to call a function on the other viewController (I think it should be a protocol) that gets the exact moment when the view was dismissed, exactly the same the imagePicker function does when you use the didFinishPickingImage parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for dismissing the view controller:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag
                           completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

If you set the flag to YES, you will see the animation of view getting dismissed.
If you set the flag to NO, the view will be dismissed right away, and you can do whatever you want in the completiton block.